# matrix on top of bitmap on canvas in android

Tags: android, matrix, canvas, bitmap

I want to apply matrix on top of bitmap in android and then apply effects on that matrix. I have tried the below code but all it does is overlays the image on top of other image.

```
               image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.stratus_cloud);
//
            setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.stratus_cloud));

            matrix2 = new Matrix();

            paint.setAntiAlias(true);

                // Free Transform bitmap
                int bw = image.getWidth();
                int bh = image.getHeight();
    
                float[] pts = {
                        // source
                        0, 0,
                        0, bh,
                        bw, bh,
                        bw, 0,
                        // destination
                        0, 0,
                        0, 0,
                        0, 0,
                        0, 0};
    
                pts[8] = CIRCLE_TOP_LEFT.x;
                pts[9] = CIRCLE_TOP_LEFT.y;
                pts[10] = CIRCLE_BOTTOM_LEFT.x;
                pts[11] = CIRCLE_BOTTOM_LEFT.y;
                pts[12] = CIRCLE_BOTTOM_RIGHT.x;
                pts[13] = CIRCLE_BOTTOM_RIGHT.y;
                pts[14] = CIRCLE_TOP_RIGHT.x;
                pts[15] = CIRCLE_TOP_RIGHT.y;
    
    
                matrix2.setPolyToPoly(pts, 0, pts, 8, 4);
                canvas.drawBitmap(image, matrix2, null);
                isTouchCirclePoints = false;
```

[image: Overlay matrix is not correct.]

I want to get this result and apply filters on above image or resize it. If resized then it will give me warping effect in that area.

[image]

Thanks